# Effective way how to handle ModelMap between Controllers, using forwarding in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

What is the most elegant/effective way, how to handle Model between Controllers in Spring MVC 3.2. For redirecting to another Controller I use forward method, so there is not necessary new instance of request and Model data should be accessible (if I am not wrong). Is there any way how to catch Model, which was added in first Controller?

(I know about RedirectAttributes, but may be is better/easier method)

Example:

```
@Controller
public class WebpageController{

        @RequestMapping( value = { "/{code}" } )
        public String handleFirstLevel(@PathVariable String code, ModelMap modelMap) throws PageNotFoundEception{
            final Webpage webpage = getWebpage(code);
            modelMap.put(WEBPAGE_MODEL_KEY, prepareModel(webpage));

            return "forward:some-url";
        }

        private Map<String, Object> prepareModel(Webpage webpage){
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            model.put("webpage", webpage);
            return model;
        }

        // some other code
    }

    @Controller
    public class SpecialWebpageController{

        @RequestMapping( value = { "/some-url" } )
        public String handleFirstLevel(@PathVariable String code, ModelMap modelMap) throws PageNotFoundEception{
            // need access to previously appended model to add some other data
            return "specialViewName";
        }

    }
```

Thank you

Comment: `forward:` will forward a `InternalResourceView` to the container so I'm not sure what you mean by forwarding to a controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a handler method that simply returns a `String`, that `String` is considered a view name. With a prefix of `forward`, Spring will get a `RequestDispatcher` for the specified path and forward to it. Part of that process will include taking the `Model` from the `ModelAndView` created for that request handling cycle and putting all its attributes into the `HttpServletRequest` attributes.

The Servlet container will take the `RequestDispatcher#forward(..)` and again use your `DispatcherServlet` to handle it. Your `DispatcherServlet` will create a *new* `ModelAndView` with a new `Model` for this handling cycle. Therefore this `Model` doesn't contain any of the attributes from before but the `HttpServletRequest` attributes do.

In your case, this

```
modelMap.put(WEBPAGE_MODEL_KEY, prepareModel(webpage));
```

will end up being in

```
HttpServletRequest request = ...;
request.getAttribute(WEBPAGE_MODEL_KEY);
```